# Add an upload button to the frontend contact form

Tags: orocommerce

I try to add an upload button to the standard contact form in Orocommerce.
I extended the entity as described in
https://doc.oroinc.com/master/backend/entities/attachments/#backend-entity-attachments and the "contact us" entity now shows a button to add an attachment in the backend.
But I still dont't understand how to actually add an upload field to the frontend (preferably in costum forms, too).
How can I change the fields that are available in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form type extension to add a field to the frontend form:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html